# How do I add internet permission to a Winform app in visual studio for windows

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

Hello I am developing a Winform app, but I can't seem to see how to add internet permission to the app. Or does Winform have automatic default internet permission?

Answer (score 2):

Any desktop app (including WinForms) has access to the network by default. There is no any permission system for this as for Android or iOS. But if the use has any firewall or other security software installed, he/she may be need to configure this software to allow your app to access network.

So, in your code you does not need perform any additional actions to get internet access.